# Unable to load handler for task

Tags: azure-devops

I've set up a windows server 2008 R2 VM. downloaded the build agent from visualstudio online. Registered it and set it up. Now for all the build types I've tried I get one of these messages (one for each type of build attempt):

`Unable to load task handler Process for task CmdLine with version 1.0.12.`

`Unable to load task handler PowerShell for task VSBuild with version 1.0.16.`

`Unable to load task handler PowerShell for task MSBuild with version 1.0.15.`

PowerShell version Information:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

The add features dialog doesn't have options like specified in [the only article](http://nakedalm.com/unable-load-task-handler-powershell-task-vsbuild/) on the internet that appears to even partially apply to this problem. However powershell is installed in the features list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build agent for VSO requires PowerShell v3 or newer. The PowerShell on your server is v2. You need to install a newer PowerShell version.

PowerShell v3: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595

PowerShell v4: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

Prerequisites for Build Agents from MSDN:

• An operating system that is supported by Visual Studio 2013 or newer

• Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015

• PowerShell 3 or newer