# Unable to load task handler PowerShell for task VSBuild with version 1.0.16

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I'm trying to set up a build server using TFS 2015.  I've got as far as setting up an agent and configuring automatic build on check-in on a collection.

The builds are failing with the message:

> Unable to load task handler PowerShell for task VSBuild with version
>   1.0.16.

In this question, the answer was that version 3 or greater of powershell was needed:   [Unable to load handler for task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526562/unable-to-load-handler-for-task)

In this case, according to the server configuration options, powershell versions 2 and 4 are installed on the server.

```
PS ..> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Visual studio 2015 pro is also installed on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was a missing Powershell environment path to the modules directory.  The fault with Powershell was confirmed by trying commands directly in Powershell (which failed).  Powershell ISE was loaded (which reported errors loading modules) and eventually the paths were compared with a known good installation and the missing path identified.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Powershell version in the **Capabilities** of the build agent on website `http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentQueue`, then update your agent as screenshot below shows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  PowerShell isn't in the capabilities list.

Although the version suggests 4 is installed, if I try to run commands like Show-Command Get-Eventlog (http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell3-whats-new.htm) I get an error.  My current theory is there is a problem with the powershell installation.